# C++ array declaration on heap?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, syntax, heap-memory

In C++ we can write:

```
    int arr[] = {20,3,2,0,-10,-7,7,0,1,22};
//Smal Note: Why int *arr = {20,3,2,0,-10,-7,7,0,1,22}; won't work? I learnt I can replace [] with *
```

but what if I want to allocated arr on heap in one line?

I tried:

```
    int arr[] = new int {20,3,2,0,-10,-7,7,0,1,22};
```

Comment: `int *arr = new int[]{...};`.

Comment: "I learnt I can replace [] with *" It should be about function arguments.

Comment: You also have the more popular `std::vector<int>`

Answer (score 1):

In **function** arguments, `int[]` means "an array of unknown size", and is technically equivalent to `int*`. (when the pointer is interpreted as a pointer to the first integer in an array).

But in your declaration, `int[]` means "an array whose size is determined by the initializer", and that is a very well-known size.

`new int[]` does create an array on the heap, but it returns a pointer to the first element. You might notice a similarity here with function arguments - it's easy to convert from an array to a pointer.

`std::vector<int>` creates an array on the heap too, but the vector object which manages the array can live anywhere. That's often a lot more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `int arr[] = {20,3,2,0,-10,-7,7,0,1,22};` your `arr` is usually stored on the stack, just like `int a=20, b=3, ...;`. In this case, the right-hand side is an initializer, which just tells how `int arr[]` is initialized.

On the other hand, if you write `int *arr = new int[]{20,3,2,0,-10,-7,7,0,1,22};` the array is created on the heap, which can only be accessed via pointers, and the pointer pointing to the array is assigned into `int *arr` which in turn is on the stack.

So in the context of declaration, `int[]` and `int*` are completely different things. But both `int[]` array and `int*` array can be accessed using the `[]` operator, e.g. `arr[2]` which is synonymous with `*(arr+2)`. And when you use `int[]` or `int*` as an argument of a function, they are completely interchangeable.